# Why do we first declare subtypes as their supertype before we instantiate them?

Tags: java, oop

Reading other people's code, I've seen a lot of:

```
List<E> ints = new ArrayList<E>();
Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();
```

My question is: what is the point/advantage of instantiating them that way as opposed to:

```
ArrayList<E> ints = new ArrayList<E>();
HashMap<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();
```

What also makes it odd is that I've never seen anything like:

```
CharSequence s = new String("String");
```

or

```
OutputStream out = new PrintStream(OutputStream);
```

> Duplicates (of the first part of the question):
>
> [When/why to use/define an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614845/when-why-to-use-define-an-interface)
>
> [Use interface or type for variable definition in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768869/use-interface-or-type-for-variable-definition-in-java)
>
> [When should I use an interface in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586389/when-best-to-use-an-interface-in-java)
>
> [why are interfaces created instead of their implementations for every class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009960/why-are-interfaces-created-instead-of-their-implementations-for-every-class)
>
> [What's the difference between these two java variable declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936558/whats-the-difference-between-theese-two-java-variable-declarations)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Quick answer? Using interfaces and superclasses increases the portability and maintainability of your code, principally by hiding implementation detail. Take the following hypothetical example:

```
class Account {
    private Collection<Transaction> transactions;

    public Account() {
        super();
        transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>(4);
    }

    public Collection<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }
}
```

I've declared a contract for an Account that states that the transactions posted to the account can be retrieved as a Collection. The callers of my code don't have to care what kind of collection my method actually returns, and shouldn't. And that frees me to change up the internal implementation if I need to, without impacting (aka breaking) unknown number of clients. So to wit, if I discover that I need to impose some kind of uniqueness on my transactions, I can change the *implementation* shown above from an ArrayList to a HashSet, with no negative impact on anyone using my class.

```
public Account() {
    super();
    transactions = new HashSet<Transaction>(4);
}
```

As far as your second question, I can say that you use the principal of portability and encapsulation wherever they make sense. There are not a terrible lot of CharSequence implementations out there, and String is by far the most used common. So you just won't see alot of developers declaring CharSequence variables in their code.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer because while it also the most thorough by providing a real-world example, the second part of my question is answered best here.

Answer (score 11):

Using interfaces has the main advantage that **you can later change the implementation** (the class) without the need to change more than the single line where you create the instance and do the assignment.

Answer (score 7):

For

```
List<E> ints = new ArrayList<E>();
Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();
```

`List` and `Map` are the interfaces, so any class implementing those interfaces can be assigned to these references.

`ArrayList` is one of the several classes (another is `LinkedList`) which implement `List` interface.

Same with `Map`. `HashMap`, `LinkedHashMap`, `TreeMap` all implement Map.

It is a general principle ***To program for interfaces and not for implementations***. Due to this, the programming task becomes easier. You can dynamically change the behavior of the references.

If you write

```
ArrayList<E> ints = new ArrayList<E>();
HashMap<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();
```

`ints` and `map` will be `ArrayList` and `HashMap` only, forever.

Answer (score 5):

Is a design principle that you [program to the interface and not to the implementation](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples.html).

That way you may provide later a new implementation to the same interface.

From the above link Eric Gamma explains:

> *This principle is really about dependency relationships which have to be carefully managed in a large app. It's easy to add a dependency on a class. It's almost too easy; just add an import statement and modern Java development tools like Eclipse even write this statement for you. Interestingly the inverse isn't that easy and getting rid of an unwanted dependency can be real refactoring work or even worse, block you from reusing the code in another context. For this reason you have to develop with open eyes when it comes to introducing dependencies. This principle tells us that depending on an interface is often beneficial.*

Here, the termin `interface` refers not only to the Java artifact, but the public interface a given object has, which is basically composed of the methods it has, so, it could be a Java interface ( like `List` in your example ) or a concrete superclass.

So in your example if you ever want to use a `LinkedList` instead it would be harder because the type is already declared as `ArrayList` when just list would've been enough.

Of course, if you need specific methods from a given implementation, you have to declare it of that type.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

[@Bhushan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8761213/971040) answered why.
To answer your confusion Why nobody uses

```
CharSequence s = new String("String");
```

or

```
OutputStream out = new PrintStream(OutputStream);
```

`CharSequence` contains only few common methods. Other classes that implement this interface are mostly buffers and only `String` is immutable. `CharSequence` defines common api for classes backed by char array and **This interface does not refine the general contracts of the equals and hashCode methods** (see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html)).

`OutputStream` is low-level api for writing data. Because `PrintStream` **adds extra convenient methods for writing** - higher level of abstraction, it's used over OutputStream.

Answer (score 3):

You do this to make sure later when working with the variable you (or anyone using your classes) won't rely on methods specific for the implementation chosen (ArrayList, HashMap, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

The reason behind this is not technical but the stuff you have to read between the lines of code: The `List` and `Map` examples says: "I'm only interested in basic list/map stuff, basically you can use anything here." An extreme example of that would be

```
Iterable<Foo> items = new ArrayList<Foo>();
```

when you really only want to do some stuff for each thing.

As an added bonus this makes it a little easier to refactor the code later into common utility classes/methods where the concrete type is not required. Or do you want to code your algorithm multiple times for each kind of collection?

The `String` example on the other hand is not seen wildly, because a) `String` is special class in Java - each `"foo"` literal is automatically a `String` and sooner or later you *have* to give the characters to some method which only accepts `String` and b) the `CharSequence` is really *ahh* minimal. It does not even support Unicode beyond the BMP properly and it misses most query/manipulation methods of `String`.

Answer (score 2):

This (good) style of declaring the type as the `Interface` the class implements is important because it forces us to use methods only defined in the `Interface`.

As a result, when we need to change our class implementations (i.e. we find our `ArraySet` is better than the standard `HashSet`) we are guaranteed that if we change the class our code will work because both classes implement the strictly-enforced `Interface`.

Answer (score 1):

It is just easier to think of `String` as of `String`. As well as it's easier (and more beneficial) to think of `WhateverList` as of `List`.

The bonuses are discussed many times, but in brief you simply separate the concerns: when you need a `CharSequence`, you use it. It's highly unlikely that you need `ArrayList` *only:* usually, any List will do.

Answer (score 1):

When you at some point decide to use a different implementation, say:

```
List<E> ints = new LinkedList<E>();
```

instead of

```
List<E> ints = new ArrayList<E>();
```

this change needs to be done **only at a single place**.

There is the right balance to strike:

usually you use the type which gives you the most appropriate guarantees. Obviously, a `List` is also a `Collection` which is also something `Iterable`. But a collection does not give you an *order*, and an iterable does not have an "add" method.

Using `ArrayList` for the variable type is also reasonable, when you want to be a bit more explicit about the need for fast random access by object position - in a LinkedList, a "get(100)" is a lot slower. (It would be nice if Java had an interface for this, but I don't think there is one. By using ArrayList, you disallow casting an array as list.)

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<E> ints = new ArrayList<E>();
```

If you write some code that deals only with `List` then it will work for any class that implements `List` (e.g. `LinkedList`, etc). But, if your code directly deals with `ArrayList` then it's limited to `ArrayList`.

```
CharSequence s = new String("String");
```

Manually instantiating a `String` object is not good. You should use string literal instead. I am just guessing the reason that you don't see `CharSequence` might because it's quite new and also, strings are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

This is programming to the interface not the implementation, as per the Gang of Four. This will help to stop the code becoming dependent on methods that are added to particular implementations only, and make it easier to change to use a different implementation if that becomes necessary for whatever reason, e.g. performance.