# Difference of using a superclass or a derivate one in declaring an object

Tags: java

What is the difference between

```
Collection c = new ArrayList();
```

And

```
ArrayList c = new ArrayList();
```

They seem to be both of type ArrayList and thus able to invoke the same methods.

Comment: Has something to do with polymorphism

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we first declare subtypes as their supertype before we instantiate them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761188/why-do-we-first-declare-subtypes-as-their-supertype-before-we-instantiate-them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Collection` is an interface that defines the highest-level of shared collection behavior, and extends `Iterable` (which just defines the `iterator()` method).

A `List` is an interface that defines the highest-level of shared `List` behavior.

`ArrayList` is an implementation of List and in general wouldn't be used in a declaration unless you need an implementation guarantee (e.g., fast indexed access), but is fine to use as a list value.

Read the docs to see the differences–they're described in the API. The implementation (`ArrayList`) will have a type-specific implementation of each method in each interface it implements.

Answer (score 2):

In the second case you can call methods on `c` that are specific to `ArrayList` as `c` is declared as type `ArrayList`.

In the first case, you can only call methods that are defined for `Collection` (and must also be in `ArrayList`).

For example, `ArrayList` declares functions that use indexes (such as `get` and `indexOf`) but Collection does not have them.